# Rails routes edit_path missing action :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following in the routes file (in my Rails 3.0 application):

```
   namespace :admin do
    resources :users  
   end
```

The link to a users edit screen look like:

```
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_user_path(user) %>
```

When I click on it I get the following error:

```
   Unknown action
   The action '2201' could not be found for Admin::UsersController
```

Missing something very obvious here, right?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you list a generic catch-all route before the resource snippet you show?

Comment: @DaveNewton that was it, there are 300 lines of routes before the admin section and one of them messes things, I will start cutting throw them and see witch one is it. Please reply to the question and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a "catch-all" route defined before the resource entry you've shown. Route matching stops at the first match; the error indicates you may have a write that attempts to use the ID as a method name.